# youtube-dl front-end Video Download - using python and flask?

Tags: python, flask, youtube-dl

How to download youtube and other website video and audio file through youtube-dl (Front-End download - WEB UI)

Search and download the video through frontend.

i have write a script is python and flask -

```
    from flask import (
    Flask, Response,
    render_template,
    request,
    redirect,
    flash,
    url_for,
    send_file,
    session,
)
import subprocess
from ydl import get_media, verify, fetch_name
from zipper import zipping
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supposed to be a secret"


@app.route("/return-file/") 
def return_file():

    import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()

    num_choice = session.get("choice")
    filename = session.get("filename")
    url = session.get("url")

    if num_choice == 1:
        filename_formatted = filename + ".mp3"
        location = "media/Audio downloads/{}.mp3".format(session.get("id"))

    if num_choice == 2:
        #filename_formatted = filename + ".mp4"
        #cc = get_media(url, num_choice)
        print(url)
        print('==============================================================================')

        #"youtube-dl", "--get-url", url
        #subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", "--no-check-certificate", "--get-url", url])

        #subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", "--no-check-certificate", url])

        test = subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", "--no-check-certificate", "--get-filename", url])

        print(test)

        csv = '1,2,3\n4,5,6\n'
        return Response(
            csv, 
            mimetype="text/csv",
            headers={"Content-disposition":
                    "attachment; filename=test"})

        #return send_file('', attachment_filename="myplot.csv")

        print('==============================================================================')
        #subprocess.run(["youtube-dl", "--no-check-certificate", url])

        #location = "media/{}.mp4".format(session.get("id"))
        #if os.path.isdir(location):
            #print('True')


    if num_choice == 3 or num_choice == 4:
        filename_formatted = filename + ".zip"
        location = "media/{}.zip".format(session.get("id"))

    #return send_file(
        #location, attachment_filename=filename_formatted, as_attachment=True
    #)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home_page():
    """
    Displaying homepage
    """

    title = "YDL | YouTube Downloader"

    if request.method == "POST":

        attempted_url = request.form["url"]
        attempted_choice = int(request.form["submit"])
        title = [attempted_url, attempted_choice]
        if attempted_url != "":
            if verify(attempted_url):

                result_id = get_media(attempted_url, attempted_choice)
                session["url"] = attempted_url
                session["id"] = result_id
                session["choice"] = attempted_choice
                filename = fetch_name(attempted_url)
                session["filename"] = filename
                # return render_template('material-life.html', title = "Success {}".format(title))
                # return render_template('material-life.html', title = result_id)
                return redirect(url_for("return_file"))
            else:
                return render_template(
                    "material-life.html", title="YDL | Doesn't belong to YouTube"
                )
        else:
            return render_template(
                "material-life.html", title="YDL | URL shouldn't be empty"
            )

    return render_template("material-life.html", title=title)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    """
    for anyone trying different links or searching for images within the server
    """
    return (
        render_template(
            "error_template.html",
            title="404 bud",
            message="Time to make the chimi-fuckin'-changas. ",
            subline="404, not there",
            image_location=url_for("static", filename="images/deadpool-funny.jpg"),
        ),
        404,
    )


@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_request(error):
    """
    For handling situations where the server doesn't know what to do with the browser's request
    """
    return (
        render_template(
            "error_template.html",
            title="Aaaah ...",
            message="나는 이해하지 못한다.",
            subline="Yeah, the server couldn't understand what you asked for, Sorry",
            image_location=url_for("static", filename="images/simpson-gangam.jpg"),
        ),
        400,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

- its working on console base download... but i want to download through front end... without save - direct download

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytube` module, which depends on `youtube-dl`.
You seem to be building an app, but with the video's url, you can use the below one-liner to download the video:

```
from pytube import YouTube    
YouTube(video_url).streams.first().download(filename='file_name')
```